# How do I stop the content with onChange?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, location-href

I have this problem with onchange:

```
<form class="form" action="javascript:update();">
      <select name="calendar" id="calendar" onchange = "update(); location.href = 'http://orario-preghiera.it/newsito/try.html?id=' + this.value">
            <option value = "x" selected="selected">Bologna</option>
            <option value = "y1">Other city</option>
            <option value = "y2">Other city</option>
            <option value = "y3">Other city</option>
            <option value = "y4">Other city</option>
            <option value = "y5">Other city</option>
      </select>
</form>
```

When I choose a **option**, from **x** (i.e. *selected*) to **y**, the URL changes to **y**, and is displays the contents of **y** for a few seconds and then returns to x (selected), but the link changes and remains. 
How can I stop the content?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need the update() twice ?

Comment: and you have an error in line 113 - $('#sfRemove').click(function(){ it say $("#sfRemove") is null

Comment: Are you kidding me? You're including jQuery TWICE and then you override $ method... sad

Comment: sorry! I'm not good in javascript. 
@yossi: the line 113 - $('#sfRemove').click(function(){ has nothing to do with script of calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that update() function is called on every page load. Seems from the debugger that it happens from the onchange method. Anyways, I'd suggest you to change the selected attribute to the active town when the page is first requested, so that you wouldnt default to the same or remove the update from onchange on the select tag.

Also, why the hell do you have jQuery loaded twice and then you override the $ method, rendering jQuery useless.

Comment: @Phoenix works exactly like it did before for me. What I mean is remove the update() function from onchange attribute on the select tag.

Comment: @Phoenix, also you have it inside switchFormat(), which gets called on page load. Try commenting it out.

Comment: @Phoenix since your Javascript is garbage, you should actually set the selected attribute to the correct one on the server side (it's always on Bologna), then the update() calls wouldn't matter. Fix that and you have your solution.

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested me, but doesn't work.
I tried to comment switchFormat(), and remove it. But nothing.
You can also try, download the file here and try: http://www.2shared.com/file/qR1NowvJ/orario.html

Thank you very much and thanks for your patience.

ps. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @Phoenix do you even have a serverside script that does something or is the javascript all there is? If so, just remove the redirect (location.href) in the onchange methods and you'll get the result. If you want bookmarkable results is javascript you have to use location.hash

Comment: Thank you very much. Great! You solved my problem. Now it works fine, Many Many thanks Zanfa. ;)